# Python randomly stops working

Tags: python, crash, window

I can run, lets say, `myscript.py` 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., X times sucessffully with no errors or problems.
Then at the X execution it crashes Windows with `"python.exe stopped working..."` message.

The problem is that X is completely random. Sometimes I can run the script a thousand times, sometimes a hundread, sometimes ten...

I don't know exactly what it can be, but I think its unrelated to the specific code because if it runs ok once, why not always? I mean, python is not even throwing execptions. It just crashes and Windows displays `"python.exe stopped working..."`.

Maybe python isn't managing memory? Any clues?

INFO: Running Python 2.7 64 on Windows 8. Dealing with `autopy` and `PIL` libs...

MORE INFO EDIT: Reproduced the error basicly using this two lines of code

```
send = autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open('send.png')
corner = autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open('corner.png')
```

Sometimes script runs ok, sometimes don't. Both loaded png files are always the same in every execution.

Comment: Possibly undefined behavior in the code - would need to see your code.

Comment: Reproduced the error basicly using this two lines of code `send = autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open('send.png')` and `corner = autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open('corner.png')`. Sometimes script runs ok, sometimes don't. Both loaded png files are always the same in every execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in

```
corner = autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open('corner.png')
```

The file `corner.png` was 8 bit png. Had to be 32 bit.

Comment: you should always accept answer if it solves the issue. Even your own: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: i know. just have to wait more 23h